# how to Insert null value in foreign key column

Tags: nhibernate, foreign-keys

I have two tables `x` and `y`. `x` has one PK column and `y` has an FK constraint of table x (with null). I need to insert null values in table y by passing null value. Is this possible in NHibernate?

I tried by passing null value but it is giving an FK constraint error.

Comment: Does the column in the database allow for NULLs ?? If not - you must supply a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

If a person table has a mobilePhone fm to a phone table, it is quite valid for the mobilePhone field to be null if the person doesn't have a mobile phone. Howver you don't need to insert a phone record with a null primary key. That would be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

foreign key can not be place as null where other table's filed is primary key. Yes offcourse default value can be assign.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a specific answer on how to do what you are asking, you need to provide more information about the tools you are using. What database system? what programming language?

However I think you have a bigger problem than how to insert a null. Even though it is a FK, it is still a key. For referential integrity there should be a PK that matched in another table. This means that there would be have to be a PK with a null somewhere too, which is something you should never do in a good database design. If at all possible look into a better design for the database tables that doesn't require you to use null keys.

Comment: I can't comment on Derek's answer but it is wrong. You wouldn't put an empty FK to a mobile table in a person table. You would have the mobile table have a FK to the person table instead. If there was no record in the mobile table that matched the PK in the person table, then the person has no mobile. So I repeat; a good database design will never have a key field, PK or FK, that allows nulls.